# Some questions on Cobra pearl real

Tags: puranas

Does cobra pearl and stone are entirely different in shape and colour? And how big is it? A tiny gel like transparent capsule as shown in by youtubers?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site, your first question looks a like a duplicate of another question.

Comment: Thank you anyway . But my question is more specific about the nagamani.